# How to rename a lot files with a loop?

Tags: php, batch-file, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I want to rename 420 files with a loop, but I don't know how.

In my project I created 420 images with fopen();

```
fopen($meal->imagepath, "w");
```

Since fopen searches for a existing file and I didn't had these, the function created my 420 files via a loop and they have the correct names. The problem now is, that these images have no properties like height, width or background-color.

Therefore I would like to **create one file manually** in paint and copy this file 420 times and then rename them by refering on a txt file with my 420 correct names. I think this should be possible, but how?

Thanks you

Comment: You can probably just either use a system call to mv or rename, depending on the OS, or the rename function of stdio. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this sounds like a one-shot thing I leave out the error handling

php directly copying the files

```
foreach( file('names.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $target)
    copy('source.png', $target);
}
```

see also: http://docs.php.net/copy , http://docs.php.net/function.file

php creating a batch file:

```
file_put_contents('rename.sh', '#!/bin/bash');
foreach( file('names.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $target)
    file_put_contents('rename.sh', "cp source.png $target\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

see also: http://docs.php.net/file_put_contents

shell/xargs only:

```
<source.txt xargs -L 1 cp source.png
```

see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Powershell:

```
gc .\source.txt | %{ copy source.png $_ }
```

see also: [Using the Get-Content Cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176843.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
  file_put_contents('new_name',file_get_contents('path/to/file/'.$filename)); }
```